# How can I prevent a PrismaticJoint from resetting to it's initial Translation Limit?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I'm working on a game that has the player orbiting around planets. I'm using a PrismaticJoint to let the player move closer and further away from the planet, and I'm orbiting the Player by rotating the center point body(bodyA of the Joint) the player (bodyB) is attached to. I move the player on the Prismatic axis by enabling the Motor and disabling the limit. However, as soon as I update and re-enable the limits of the PrismaticJoint, the body jumps back to its original position and the PrismaticJoint limit returns to it's original limit.

I've tried tweaking it a million different ways and no matter what I do as *soon* as I re-enable the limit (and no matter what the new limit should be) it always snaps to the original limit and position. I use SpriteBody, which is a class that extends a Sprite and has a body. Everything except the new limit being applied is executed as expected.
Here's the method that is called to create the Prismatic Joint-- (please note currentThrustJoint is a public field and always accesible, as is it's FixtureDef)

```
// sprite is the SpriteBody that the Player orbits
private void setOrbit(PlanetaryCenter sprite){
    // Get Player (which is a SpriteBody)
    Player player = (Player) resources.get("player");
    // Updated Sprite Body Physics / Rotation
    thrustJointDef = new PrismaticJointDef();

    // Set up the thrustJointDef Correctly

    thrustJointDef.collideConnected = false;
    thrustJointDef.enableMotor = false;
    thrustJointDef.maxMotorForce = 20f;

    thrustJointDef.lowerTranslation = sprite.getBody().getWorldCenter().dst(player.getBody().getWorldCenter());
    thrustJointDef.upperTranslation = sprite.getBody().getWorldCenter().dst(player.getBody().getWorldCenter());
    thrustJointDef.motorSpeed = 5;
    thrustJointDef.initialize(sprite.getBody(), player.getBody(), 
            sprite.getBody().getWorldCenter(), new Vector2(0, 1f));


    // Update focus to the new orbit point
    sprite.isFocus = true;

    // Change currentOrbit to the new orbit point's user data
    currentOrbit = (String) sprite.getUserData();

    currentThrustJoint = (PrismaticJoint) this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(thrustJointDef);
    currentThrustJoint.enableLimit(true);
 }
```

Here's how I create the Player, and then later the OrbitPoint. Both are done before setOrbit is called.

```
// Create Player Body/Physics
Player player = new Player(400-25, 400 + 400, player_default, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
player.setRotationCenter(player.getWidth()/2, player.getHeight()/2);
player.setBody(PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, player, BodyType.DynamicBody, playerFixtureDef));
    mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(player, player.getBody(), true, true));
resources.put("player", player);

....
    // create the orbitpoint for the center
    PlanetaryCenter orbitCenter = new PlanetaryCenter(center_x_old, center_y_old, planet_center, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    orbitCenter.setRotationCenter(50, 50);
    orbitCenter.setBody(PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, orbitCenter, BodyType.KinematicBody, wallFixtureDef));
    mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(orbitCenter, orbitCenter.getBody(), false, true));
    orbitCenter.getBody().setUserData("orbit" + z);

    mScene.registerTouchArea(orbitCenter);
    // store in hashMap
    resources.put(("orbit" + z), orbitCenter);

    // attach the initial center point in the construct to the scene
    mScene.attachChild(orbitCenter);
```

And finally, where most important bits- where I turn the limit off, and then where I turn it back on:

```
private void setThrust(){ // called when the user taps a thrust key
    Player thisPlayer = (Player) resources.get("player");
    PlanetaryCenter thisOrbit = (PlanetaryCenter) resources.get(currentOrbit);
    thisPlayer.throttling = true;

    currentThrustJoint.enableLimit(false);

    if(ascButton.clicked) currentThrustJoint.setMotorSpeed(5f);
    else currentThrustJoint.setMotorSpeed(-5f);

    currentThrustJoint.enableMotor(true);

}
.... called in TouchListener on Scene...
Player thisPlayer = (Player) resources.get("player");
PlanetaryCenter thisOrbit = (PlanetaryCenter) resources.get(currentOrbit);

thisPlayer.throttling = false;
currentThrustJoint.setMotorSpeed(0);
currentThrustJoint.enableMotor(false);
float newLimit = currentThrustJoint.getJointTranslation(); // intended amt, but it doesn't matter what number it is- never changes
currentThrustJoint.setLimits(newLimit, newLimit);
currentThrustJoint.enableLimit(true);
currentThrustJoint.enableMotor(false);
```

I know it's a lot but I would really appreciate a second set of eyes on this, I've sunk four days into trying to figure out what I overlooked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Smells like a bug. The getJointTranslation and setLimits calls you have should clamp the joint at the current position. I don't see any limits being set when you create the joint so we can assume you are going with the default limits of 0 and 0? Does getJointTranslation return some non-zero value? Are the limits affected if you set them to something non-zero when creating the joint? Do the getLowerLimit/getUpperLimit functions return the values you set as expected?

Comment: Oh god, I hope not. I am going with the default, but even if I change it, it doesn't change the snapping behavior. Furthermore, it always snaps back to it's default distance from the center, even if the initial limit is changed, but it will still update the rotation consistently and correctly.

Did some debugging and getJointTransform always returns the expected value and getLowerLimit/getUpperLimit return the right values immediately after enabling the new limit.

I'm stumped. I'll search my code for any lost Fixtures that might be mussing this up.

Comment: So getJointTranslation, getLowerLimit, and getUpperLimit all return the correct value... then after the next Step() they get messed up? Is it possible to just set the motor speed to zero and give it a strong force to hold it there?

Comment: I did try that and it did not work, because it requires limits to be disabled to apply the force and when utilizing said Joint, it can slide every-which-way. Asked the creator on the AndEngine forum and he had no clue why it was happening, he did give me a solution though (which is posted as my own answer). Thanks for the help!

Comment: I mean not use limits at all, but try to rely on a strong force to act as a brake. If there are no other objects bumping it around it should hold.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this on the AndEngine forums and someone said to try destroying and recreating the joint each time you want to change the limit. Save the JointDef you initially create the Joint with, destroy the joint, initialize it again, and then recreate the joint. Works like a charm! It doesn't seem too performance costly because I'm resetting the limit infrequently, but if you're looking to create a PrismaticJoint that can slide a body rapidly by just changing the limit, you'll probably have to try another joint. (I'd say a DistanceJoint or something but I haven't tested that)

Still no clues on why this is happening, but I'd say the PhysicsEngine doesn't acknowledge some of the updated PrismaticJoint values in its calculations. Think it's a bug.

Comment: Indeed. I should not say too much since I have never used the AndEngine version myself, but I can at least say for the C++ version that you should not need to recreate the joint.